# Control windows desktop program via windows phone app (bluetooth)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bluetooth, windows-desktop-gadgets

I would like to create a Windows Phone app that is able to control a Windows Desktop program. My questions are:

- If the computer does not have bluetooth connection, can I use a usb bluetooth connector?
- Can I control a software in the computer and send data back and forward between computer and mobile phone, considering that it has open APIs?
- Am I also able to create folders in the computer?
- And last one, what language and tools would you think are best suited for the job?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, if the BT connector supports a socket API

2) Yes, you can send data to a receiving client that is listening

3) The phone will not do this directly.  It's the commands that run on the client machine that will do this.

4) It doesn't matter which language you use on the phone.  The phone will be sending commands of your choice to the client machine, which will have the desktop app running on it.  The client desktop app will control everything that is allowed to happen on the client machine.  The phone app will simply tell it what to do, as long a the desktop app exposes that functionality.